# Set NSDate 0 seconds in swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, nsdatepicker

I'm trying to get `NSDate` from `UIDatePicker`, but it constantly returns me a date time with trailing 20 seconds. How can I manually set `NSDate`'s second to zero in swift?

Comment: I need this in swift

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525825/how-to-set-seconds-to-zero-for-nsdate

You can use same way in swift

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1525907/4185345) in Swift:

```
var date = NSDate();
let timeInterval = floor(date .timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate() / 60.0) * 60.0
date = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: timeInterval)
```

Comment: I think it's the best option because it doesn't introduce optionality.

Answer (score 42):

```
extension Date {

    var zeroSeconds: Date? {
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        let dateComponents = calendar.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute], from: self)
        return calendar.date(from: dateComponents)
    }

}
```

Usage:

```
let date1 = Date().zeroSeconds

let date2 = Date()
print(date2.zeroSeconds)
```

Answer (score 8):

Truncating a date to a full minute can be done with

```
let date = NSDate()

let cal = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
var fullMinute : NSDate?
cal.rangeOfUnit(.CalendarUnitMinute, startDate: &fullMinute, interval: nil, forDate: date)
println(fullMinute!)
```

Update for **Swift 4** and later:

```
let date = Date()
let cal = Calendar.current
if let fullMinute = cal.dateInterval(of: .minute, for: date)?.start {
    print(fullMinute)
}
```

This method can easily be adapted to truncate to a full hour, day, month, ...

Comment: This strikes me as the best way to do this. Any date calculation that includes "`60`" in it makes me shiver! Don't get me started on "`60 * 60`" or even "`60 * 60 * 24`"!!

Comment: What if the `Date` to-be-truncated has the exact same value, won't it always "skip" to the next/previous `Date`?

Comment: @GuilhermeMatuella: You are right, if the date is already on an full minute then it would yield the previous minute. I have removed that part, thank you for the feedback.

Answer (score 7):

This is how to do it in **Swift 3**.

In this example I remove the seconds in the date components:

```
let date = picker.date
let calendar = Calendar.current
let components = calendar.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute], from: date)
let fullMinuteDate = calendar.date(from: components)!
```

Working on a playground:
[image: Removing the seconds component from a date]

Answer (score 1):

Just reformat the date:

```
func stripSecondsFromDate(date: NSDate) -> NSDate {
  let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
  dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"
  let str = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date)
  let newDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(str)!

  return newDate
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import Foundation

let now = Date()
let calendar = Calendar.current
let date = calendar.date(bySettingHour: 0,
                         minute: 0,
                         second: 0,
                         of: now,
                         direction: .backward)
```

There is another way, with two more parameters: [matchingpolicy](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/calendar/matchingpolicy) and [repeatedTimePolicy](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/calendar/repeatedtimepolicy).

```
let date = calendar.date(bySettingHour: 0,
                         minute: 0,
                         second: 0,
                         of: now,
                         matchingPolicy: .strict,
                         repeatedTimePolicy: .first,
                         direction: .backward)
```

To check the result:

```
let formatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()
formatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current // defaults to GMT
let string = formatter.string(from: date!)
print(string) // 2019-03-27T00:00:00+01:00
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this doesn't address `NSDate` directly, but it might be worth anyways - I had this exact same problem with `Date` and also because I think this **might** be a more **clean** approach.

```swift
extension Calendar {
    /// Removes seconds `Calendar.Component` from a `Date`. If `removingFractional` is `true`, it also
    /// removes all fractional seconds from this particular `Date`.
    ///
    /// `removingFractional` defaults to `true`.
    func removingSeconds(fromDate date: Date, removingFractional removesFractional: Bool = true) -> Date? {
        let seconds = component(.second, from: date)
        let noSecondsDate = self.date(byAdding: .second, value: -seconds, to: date)

        if removesFractional, let noSecondsDate = noSecondsDate {
            let nanoseconds = component(.nanosecond, from: noSecondsDate)
            return self.date(byAdding: .nanosecond, value: -nanoseconds, to: noSecondsDate)
        }

        return noSecondsDate
    }
}
```

Now, to solve your problem, we created the function `removingSeconds(fromDate: removingFractional)`. It's really simple - as you can see in the docs of the function. It removes the `.second` component and, if `removingFractional` is `true`, it also removes any fractional seconds that this `Date` may have - or the `.nanosecond` component.

Comment: Note that this does not remove *fractional seconds,* so that the result is not necessarily on a full minute.

Comment: @MartinR I've updated the solution to handle such scenarios where fractional seconds may be necessary to take into consideration. Do you think this is a decent approach now?

Comment: Well, you have a method to remove seconds (including fractional seconds) now. But what is the purpose of removing other units? Note that `cal.removing(component: .day, fromDate: d)` gives you a *the last day of the previous month* because days start counting at 1.  As an example, "2020-02-21 12:34" would become "2020-01-31 12:34". I am not sure if that is useful, to be honest.

Comment: You're totally correct. I've removed the abstraction that would probably cause confusion if used in any `Calendar.Component` that is "greater" than `.second` - or anything that does not relate to Time directly. Thanks, I've once again improved the answer to be more straightforward.